# Passing variables through classes and using .get() in Tkinter to find users input

Tags: python, class, variables, tkinter, parameter-passing

```
class Menu():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def menuWindow(self):
        
        menu = Tk()
        menu.title("Menu")
        menu.geometry("300x250")

        menuFrame = Frame(menu)
        menuFrame.pack()
        
        menu = Menu()
        
        menuLabel = Label(menuFrame, font="Helvetica 18 bold", text="MENU")
        menuLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)


        cDirF = TaskWindowMaker()
        cDir = Button(menuFrame, text="Create Directory", command=cDirF.cDirWindow, height=2,width=20)
        cDir.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        
        cProfF = TaskWindowMaker()
        cProf = Button(menuFrame, text="Create Profiles", command=cProfF.cProfWindow, height=2,width=20)
        cProf.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        
        dProfF = TaskWindowMaker()
        dProf = Button(menuFrame, text="Delete Profiles", command=dProfF.dProfWindow, height=2,width=20)
        dProf.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)

        mSenderF = TaskWindowMaker()
        mSender = Button(menuFrame, text="Make Sender", command=mSenderF.mSenderWindow, height=2,width=20)
        mSender.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W)
        
        sendParcelF = TaskWindowMaker()
        sParcel = Button(menuFrame, text="Send Parcel", command=sendParcelF.sendParcelWindow, height=2,width=20)
        sParcel.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)
    
    
class ProfileDeveloper(object):
def __init__(self,):
    pass
def create_folder_profiles(self):
    global directoryNamecProfWindow

    y = False
    while y == False:
        path = os.getcwd()
        print(path)

        y = numbercProfWindow.get()#int(input("Number of profiles: "))
        print(y)
        #y = int(y)
        p = os.getcwd()+("\profiles")#Reading number file in profiles
        n = ("number")
        d = os.path.join(p,n)
        try:
            dirName = directoryNamecProfWindow.get()#input("Directory name :")
            print(dirName+"OO")
            path = os.getcwd()+("\profiles")
            folderDir = os.path.join(path, dirName)
            with open(folderDir+"profile.txt","x") as f:
                print("Opened.")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found.")
        except FileExistsError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error","File already exists.")

        for a in range(y):
            with open(d+".txt","r") as z:
                num = z.read()
            num = int(num)
            newNum = (int(num)+1)
            numProf = ("profile"+str(newNum))
            with open(d+".txt","w") as file:
                file.write(str(newNum))
            path = os.getcwd()+("\profiles")
            folderDir = os.path.join(path, dirName,numProf)
            with open(folderDir+".txt","x") as f:
                print("Created '"+numProf+"'.")
        y = True
            #except:
    print("Saved to "+folderDir+"\n")
     
     
class TaskWindowMaker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def cProfWindow(self):

        global numbercProfWindow
        cProf = Tk()
        cProf.title("Create Profiles")
        cProf.geometry("300x250")

        cProfFrame = Frame(cProf)
        cProfFrame.pack()
                
        titleLabel = Label(cProfFrame, font="Helvetica 18 bold", text="Create Profiles")
        titleLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        
        menuLabel = Label(cProfFrame, text="Folder Name")
        menuLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        directoryNamecProfWindow = StringVar()
        cDirEntry = Entry(cProfFrame, textvariable=directoryNamecProfWindow)
        cDirEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        menuLabel = Label(cProfFrame, text="Number of Profiles")
        menuLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        
        numbercProfWindow = StringVar()
        cDirEntry = Entry(cProfFrame, textvariable=numbercProfWindow)
        cDirEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

        cProfF = ProfileDeveloper(directoryNamecProfWindow)
        cDir = Button(cProfFrame, text="Enter", command=cProfF.create_folder_profiles, height=2,width=20)
        cDir.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

start = Menu()
start.menuWindow()
```

This is my code. I'm opening multiple Windows. Then when I enter in an input box in

```
numbercProfWindow = StringVar()
        cDirEntry = Entry(cProfFrame, textvariable=numbercProfWindow)
        cDirEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
```

I'm then using the button:

```
cProfF = ProfileDeveloper(directoryNamecProfWindow)
        cProf = Button(cProfFrame, text="Enter", command=cProfF.create_folder_profiles, height=2,width=20)
        cProf.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
```

To send the input to ProfileDeveloper.create_folder_profiles
When it's sent to ProfileDeveloper.create_folder_profiles the program doesn't recognise the input, as in it's not '.get()ing it'.

I'm quite new so don't know how to pass variables between different functions and using the .get() function or global variables.

The main aim of the program is creating a profiles (txt files) in a specified folder. Instead of it being a script in shell I'm trying to add a Tkinter GUI.

Hopefully this explains it as I've asked before and people just get too confused. There's still a lot of code which I don't show but the confusion between passing variables continues throughout the code so not sure. The code was really long and just running in Shell then I added the Tkinter GUI and it's complicated it all by doubling variables and now this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

**Thanks :)**

Comment: Globals are rarely the right solution - to be honest I would suggest you wind back a bit - if you don't know how to pass values between functions, you need to look at function arguments https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions; but it does feel like you are trying to run a marathon before you can walk.

Answer (score 1):

Does this example help You understand better what You can do:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Button


root = Tk()


class UserInput:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.entry = Entry(self.master)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.button = Button(self.master, text='Submit', command=self.submit)
        self.button.pack()

    def submit(self):
        entry_var = self.entry.get()
        print(entry_var)


user_input = UserInput(root)
root.mainloop()
```